# Pandigital Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, number-property

**Can you find the 10 digit number* which contains each of the digits 0-9* exactly once, and when divided by 9 the quotient is a perfect cube which has the digit 7 in it exactly twice*?**

*in its base 10 representation

For clarification:

- 1014107283 does not qualify, since although 483<sup>3</sup>=112678587 has two 7s, when multiplied by 9 the product (1014107283) is missing digits 5, 6 and 9.
- 1963504872 does not qualify, since although 602<sup>3</sup>=218167208 and when multiplied by 9 the product 1963504872 is pandigital, 218167208 has only one 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is

> 1905378624

which, divided by 9 gives

> 211708736

which contains two sevens and is the third power of

> 596